# Multiple screen java applet has buttons that don't work

Tags: java, swing, button, applet, jbutton

I'm making a program that has 2 screens, a title and a game screen. If the user clicks "Play", they can proceed to the next screen. However, on the next screen if the user tries to press the button "Keep Going", nothing happens. I want to know why this is and if anyone can fix it. Thanks, and here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ZombieDice extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
Panel p_card;
Panel card1, card2;
CardLayout cdLayout = new CardLayout ();

int shotguns = 0;
int brains = 0;
int p1b = 0;
int p2b = 0;

JLabel pic1;
JLabel pic2;
JLabel pic3;

public void init ()
{
    p_card = new Panel ();
    p_card.setLayout (cdLayout);
    screen1 ();
    screen2 ();
    resize (600, 500);
    setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
    add ("Center", p_card);
}


public void screen1 ()
{
    card1 = new Panel ();
    JLabel logo = new JLabel (createImageIcon ("logo.jpg"));

    JButton play = new JButton (createImageIcon ("play.jpg"));
    play.setActionCommand ("2");
    play.addActionListener (this);

    JButton quit = new JButton (createImageIcon ("quit.jpg"));
    quit.setActionCommand ("quit");
    quit.addActionListener (this);

    card1.add (logo);
    card1.add (play);
    card1.add (quit);
    setBackground (Color.red);

    p_card.add ("1", card1);
}


public void screen2 ()
{
    card2 = new Panel ();
    JLabel player = new JLabel ("Player 1             ");
    player.setFont (new Font ("Vinque", Font.BOLD, 20));

    JLabel shotgun = new JLabel ("Shotguns: " + shotguns + "          ");
    shotgun.setFont (new Font ("Vinque", Font.BOLD, 14));
    JLabel brain = new JLabel ("Braaainss: " + brains);
    brain.setFont (new Font ("Vinque", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel p1brains = new JLabel ("Player 1 Ate: " + p1b + " Braaiinnss            ");
    p1brains.setFont (new Font ("Vinque", Font.BOLD, 16));

    JLabel p2brains = new JLabel ("Player 2 Ate: " + p2b + " Braaiinnss");
    p2brains.setFont (new Font ("Vinque", Font.BOLD, 16));

    pic1 = new JLabel (createImageIcon ("zombie.jpg"));
    pic2 = new JLabel (createImageIcon ("zombie.jpg"));
    pic3 = new JLabel (createImageIcon ("zombie.jpg"));

    JButton keepgoing = new JButton (createImageIcon ("keepgoing.jpg"));
    keepgoing.addActionListener (this);
    keepgoing.setActionCommand ("kg");

    JButton stopscore = new JButton (createImageIcon ("stopAndScore.jpg"));
    keepgoing.addActionListener (this);
    keepgoing.setActionCommand ("ss");

    JButton nextplayer = new JButton (createImageIcon ("nextPlayer.jpg"));
    nextplayer.addActionListener (this);
    nextplayer.setActionCommand ("np");

    card2.add (player);
    card2.add (shotgun);
    card2.add (brain);
    card2.add (p1brains);
    card2.add (p2brains);
    card2.add (pic1);
    card2.add (pic2);
    card2.add (pic3);
    card2.add (keepgoing);
    card2.add (stopscore);
    card2.add (nextplayer);

    p_card.add ("2", card2);
}


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand ().equals ("2"))
        cdLayout.show (p_card, "2");

    if (e.getActionCommand ().equals ("kg"))
    {
        int n = (int) ((Math.random () * 9) + 1);
        {
            if (n == 1)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n == 2)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenFootPrints.jpg"));
            else if (n == 3)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenShotGun.jpg"));
            else if (n == 4)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n == 5)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redFootPrints.jpg"));
            else if (n == 6)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redShotGun.jpg"));
            else if (n == 7)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n == 8)
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowFootPrints.jpg"));
            else
                pic1.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowShotGun.jpg"));
        }
        int n2 = (int) ((Math.random () * 9) + 1);
        {
            if (n2 == 1)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 2)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenFootPrints.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 3)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenShotGun.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 4)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 5)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redFootPrints.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 6)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redShotGun.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 7)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowBrain.jpg"));
            else if (n2 == 8)
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowFootPrints.jpg"));
            else
                pic2.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowShotGun.jpg"));
        }
        int n3 = (int) ((Math.random () * 9) + 1);
        if (n3 == 1)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenBrain.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 2)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenFootPrints.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 3)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("greenShotGun.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 4)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redBrain.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 5)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redFootPrints.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 6)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("redShotGun.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 7)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowBrain.jpg"));
        else if (n3 == 8)
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowFootPrints.jpg"));
        else
            pic3.setIcon (createImageIcon ("yellowShotGun.jpg"));
    }
}


protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon (String path)
{
    java.net.URL imgURL = ZombieDice.class.getResource (path);
    if (imgURL != null)
    {
        return new ImageIcon (imgURL);
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println ("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `p_card.add ("1", card1);` is the wrong way to add components, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Component)) *"This method is obsolete as of 1.1. Please use the method add(Component, Object) instead."*

Comment: You should also beware that `Applet` hasn't been mainstream for more than 16 years and applets generally are no longer support; see [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer but the screen changing works. just the button, "Keep Going" on screen 2 does not work the way I programmed it to.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's an assignment, not a personal game i'm making. so please try to help if possible

Comment: But the functionality is deprecated

Comment: @MadProgrammer but my other programs work just fine, and my teacher wants me to specifically use applets to make this..

Comment: Time for a new teacher, may have them have a look at [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) - And I'm refering mostly to `add(String, Component`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer LOOOL but are you sure that there is no real solution to this problem? is my actionPerformed the way it should be??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should have a closer look at these two blocks...

```
JButton keepgoing = new JButton("kg", createImageIcon("keepgoing.jpg"));
keepgoing.addActionListener(this);
keepgoing.setActionCommand("kg");


JButton stopscore = new JButton("ss", createImageIcon("stopAndScore.jpg"));
keepgoing.addActionListener(this);
keepgoing.setActionCommand("ss");
```

See anything funny?

- With regards to `JComponent#add(String, Component)` - *"This method is obsolete as of 1.1. Please use the method add(Component, Object) instead."*
- [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)
- [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: can you explain what I need to fix?

Comment: Have a CLOSE look at those to blocks of code, which run together in your code, what is the same between, which shouldn't be

Comment: @MadProgrammer So in regards to the whole `stop teaching java applets`... Would just learning swing be better?

Comment: @3kings That's a debatable question, with Oracle's current push on JavaFX, Swing is been relegated to maintenance only and if we ever see Java 2.0, it's unlikely that Swing would be brought forward. Personally, if you're interested in UI, HTML5, CSS and JavaScript and/or mobile development would be my focus

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Oracle's current push on JavaFX"* I'll consider Oracle being serious about Java-FX the moment it makes it into the J2SE Java Docs and tutorial. I heard it had failed to 'make it' for Java 9 and I fear another .. JMF, SaverBeans, Java-3D, JavaHelp .. - a quiet and slow abandonment of what might have become great APIs.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think the idea of having separate (like Swing started out as) is not make core API more flexible, rather than further burdening it down with code which "may" become defunct in the future (I like Swing). Personally, I'd like to see the core API cut down to bear mins and the rest of the APIs (like Swing, JDBC, maybe even the collections API) as "official" libraries, but that's just me :P.  Oracle didn't purchase Sun for Java, so why should they care about it ;). I'd like to see all the "deprecated" functionality removed as well, about time to cut loose the trash ;)

Comment: *"I'd like to see the core API cut down to bear mins and the rest of the APIs (like Swing, JDBC, maybe even the collections API) as "official" libraries"* Yeah, that would be optimal. Especially if Oracle can manage to do a seamless download/install of the other APIs according to application requirement (with no specific input from the app. beyond requesting a class in one of those APIs - much like JWS based 'lazy' downloads). In a *perfect* world.. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, we've seen a few dependency management systems coming out, so, conceptually it's possible ... but Oracle...